# How to render an xls with formulas already rendered in fields?

Tags: ruby, excel

I am using a Ruby script to parse an .xls file. In a field, it uses a concatenate function, like this:

`=CONCATENATE("EAN:", U2)`

However, when my ruby script parses the .xls and this field, it is not being parsed as plain text. I am seeing something like this, where the text should be:

`#<Spreadsheet`

I put a debug break statement to get a closer look: 

`[1] pry(#<DataShift::SpreeEcom::ProductLoader>)> property_list
=> ["#<Spreadsheet::Formula:0x0000000966ea00>"]`

I am using the datashift_spree gem.

Comment: How do you access the contents of the field?

Comment: Need more details on the script. Are you using a gem?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to append a .value to the end to get the value out.

Details on the fix here: https://github.com/autotelik/datashift_spree/issues/56